# How to print the amount of same integers that my 2 arrays have? [C]

Tags: c, arrays

I have problem with my code I need to make. I have to take 14 parameters from command line and use them to make lottery numbers, winning numbers and then compare those 2 with each other.

For example using this parameter: `./a.out 2 30 17 8 6 19 24 7 6 1 2 3 5 4`

Should make something like this:

```
Winning numbers: 2 30 17 8 6 19 24
Lottonumbers: 7 6 1 2 3 5 4

2 are the same: 6 2
```

My code is almost working as intended, but I can't seem to print this right: **2 are the same**. It always loops like this: `1 are the same: 6 2 are the same: 2`.

Number 2 is the amount of same numbers that are found when 2 arrays are compared. My question is how can I print it so that it won't duplicate the text and with the right amount? My head can't seem to work even if it's so simple :/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int args, char **argv)
{    
    int i;
    int winningNumbers[7];
    int lottoNumbers[7];
    int j;
    int a;
    int b;
    int winningNumber;
    int lottoNumber;
    int count = 0;

    printf("Winning numbers: ");

    for (i=0;i<7; i++) {    
        winningNumber = atoi(argv[i+1]);    
        winningNumbers[i] = winningNumber;    
        printf("%d ", winningNumber);    
    }

    printf("\n");    
    printf("Lotto numbers:: ");

    for (j= 8; j < args; j++) {

        lottoNumber = atoi(argv[j]);    
        lottoNumbers[j-8] = lottoNumber;    
        printf("%d ", lottoNumber);

    }
    printf("\n");

    for(a = 0; a < 7; a++) {

        for(b=0; b < 7; b++) {
            if (lottoNumbers[a] == winningNumbers[b]) {
                count = count + 1;
                printf("%d are the same: %d", count, winningNumbers[b]);

            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Move `printf("%d are the same: %d", count, winningNumbers[b]);` below the 2 for loops, and change it to `printf("%d are the same", count);`

Comment: move out your printf from if condition if you don't want to duplicate the text.

Comment: IMHO, store the same numbers found in a third array. Then print the third array at the exit of the loop.

Comment: Tip: change `for (i=0;i<7; i++)` to `for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)` and adjust your `argv[i+1]` to simply `argv[i]` it cuts down on the potential for mistake in adjusting indexes... and will handle all arguments without using a *magic number* like `7` for the limit.

Comment: That was such stupid mistake.. but thanks a lot for responses! I got it work now!

Comment: Take comfort, *it won't be your last...*, it's a fringe benefit of programming.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for matches and displaying the result are two separate tasks. It is simpler and more flexible not to attempt to do them at the same time.

First search for the matches and store them in an array. Then display the content of the array however you want.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int winningNumbers[7];
    int lottoNumbers[7];
    int commonNumbers[7];
    int count = 0;

    // fill winningNumbers
    // fill lottoNumbers

    // NOTE: the following loop assumes that in both arrays
    // no number is repeated.
    // You should check that this is indeed the case.
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (lottoNumbers[i] == winningNumbers[j]) {
                commonNumbers[count] = lottoNumbers[i];
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf ("%d are the same:", count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf (" %d", commonNumbers[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Many simple programs should follow this structure:

1. read and check input
2. transform input to output
3. print output

Answer (score -1):

```
for(b=0; b < 7; b++) {
    if (lottoNumbers[a] == winningNumbers[b]) {
        count = count + 1;
    }
}
printf("%d are the same: ", count);
for(b=0; b < 7; b++) {
    if (lottoNumbers[a] == winningNumbers[b]) {
    printf(" %d", winningNumbers[b]);
    }
}
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int finalArray[7];
int i;
for(a = 0; a < 7; a++) {
    for(b=0; b < 7; b++) {
        if (lottoNumbers[a] == winningNumbers[b]) {
            finalArray[count] = lottoNumbers[a];
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
}
printf("%d are same: ", count);
for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    printf("%d ", finalArray[i]);
```